# CSS Child Links using Container Div CSS

Tags: html, css, styling

I have 3 divs inside a div. I have set CSS to style links for the main div and the child div. However the div1 links don't appear to be using the div1 styling.

HTML

```
 <div id="content">
    <div class="div1">Sort By: <a href="" id="list_users_title" >A-Z</a> / <a href="" id="oneline">Genre</a></div>
        <div class="div2">
        <p>Random</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div3">
        <p>Random</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#414042;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:right;
margin-top:-26px;
margin-bottom:18px;
}

.div1  a {color:#414042; text-decoration: none; }
.div1  a:visited {color:#414042; text-decoration: none;}
.div1  a:hover { color: #b91200; text-decoration: underline; }


#content  a {color: #b91200; text-decoration: none;}
#content  a:visited {color: #b91200; text-decoration: none;}
#content a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 668px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    padding-top:42px;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9Wvbs/

Comment: I don't see why you guys are saying it "works fine" when the links are red whereas they clearly are intended to be gray.

Comment: What is your expected styling? `#content a` will override the styling of `.div1 a`, as it has higher specificity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#content a` has a higher specificity than `.div1 a`, so the links are coming out styled according to `#content a`. Try using `#content .div1 a` instead of just `.div1 a`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your style cascade for the .div1 anchor tags to be more specific:

```
#content .div1  a {color:#414042; text-decoration: none; }
#content .div1  a:visited {color:#414042; text-decoration: none;}
#content .div1  a:hover { color: #b91200; text-decoration: underline; }
```

This will allow them to override the #content a style cascade.